# How to configure jTDS logging when imported via Maven?

Tags: maven, jtds

I'd like to know how can I configure jTDS logging when it's imported via Maven dependency.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add a Dependency in your pom.xml, as shown below

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
    <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hey, @Clement. I'd like to know how to configure logging. The dependency is already defined.